# how to strictly find substring of string in java?

Tags: java, string, substring

I want to find particular string in JAVA and I am using CONTAINS function for that.

But problem with CONTAINS is that it gives true even if there is a super string available for that string.

Ex- let's say

```
String i = "anand > 5 or id < 6"
```

and I want to check whether string contains AND or OR. But here `i.contains("and")` will give true because of anand.

How to solve this issue?

Is there any function available in library?

Comment: public class java.lang.String extends java.lang.Object { public int substr(String str) { } }

Comment: just curious, what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (i.matches("(?s).*\\b(and|or)\\b.*")) System.println("AND or OR found");
```

`(?s)` let . also match newlines
`\\b` is a word boundary

---

***In answer to comment "hey now I wanted..."***

```
String[] words = ...;
StringBuilder expr = new StringBuilder();
for (String word : words) {
    if (expr.length() != 0)
        expr.append("|"):
    expr.append(word);
}
i = i.replaceAll("\\b(" + expr + ")\\b", "bla");
```

Comment: can you explain it more in context of my example...??

Comment: hey now I wanted to match string stored in an array...
If main string contains that string of array then I want to replace it...
Can you suggest me for this.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at regular expressions and use the following regex:

```
"\\band\\b"
```

The `\\b` should denote the regex to match whole words only.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check whether your string contains AND or OR then it is wrong to check `i.contains("and")` you should use contains method with case sensitive. to check whether string contains AND you need to write `contains("AND")`

```
String i = "anand > 5 or id < 6";
        System.out.println(i.contains("AND"));//returns false

        System.out.println(i.contains("and"));//returns true
```

because the **string contains and not AND** it is case sensitive

Comment: @Downvoters, mention your precious reason behind down voting. which will help others to know their mistakes. Dont hide yourself by not mentioning the reason.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you want to check for " AND " (with spaces) instead of just "and"

Comment: No I want to strictly find whether string contains AND...?? But function will give true even in cases like ANAND,HAND,SAND etc...

Comment: What do you mean `strictly`? If you want it to be so strict, use the `equals` method! light_303's method of checking for ` AND ` will work and WON'T give true for strings like `ANAND`.

Comment: String test = "sand or nosand";
boolean containsAnd = test.contains(" and ");

Comment: Your requirement is not clear : can you post exemples of string that should return True and String that should return false ? For instance is ANDOGAMY a valid string ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this : 
- fist upper case the sting you are searching for (to avoid or/OR and/AND issues)
- search for " and " (ie with leading and trailing space)

Answer (score 0):

Looks you want regular expressions where you surround the word you are looking for with word breaks, i.e.

```
"\\bAND\\b"
```

This will match AND only when it is not surrounded by other letters.

Answer (score 0):

You want whole word search. It could be done with regexps:

```
i.matches("\\band\\b")
```

where \b stands for word boundary